# Question about even degree vertices in Proof of Eulerian Circuits

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on proving the theorem that,

> For a connected multi-graph G, G is Eulerian if and only if every vertex has even degree. By Eulerian here, I mean a graph that has a Eulerian Circuit. In this question I am focused on the (=>) direction of the proof.

I am using the following [Proof](http://www.math.uri.edu/~eaton/Euler.pdf), which is as followed:

> If G is Eulerian then there is an Euler circuit, P, in
>   G. Every time a vertex is listed, that accounts for two edges
>   adjacent to that vertex, the one before it in the list and the one
>   after it in the list. This circuit uses every edge exactly once.
>   So every edge is accounted for and there are no repeats. Thus
>   every degree must be even.

How does the proof follow?

Edit: I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no choice of exit edge involved here as we assume a *fixed* Euler circuit given. Of $v$ is a vertex of $G$ and is visited by the given Euler circuit $k$ times (and is not the starting=ending vertex of it), then this vertex is "entered" $k$ times and "left" $k$ times, and each time via a *different* edge. This accounts for $2k$ different edges incident with $v$, and on the other hand, it must account for *all* edges incident with $v$.

The starting vertex has one "extra" leave, the ending vertex an extra enter, so if the starting and ending vertex coincide, we still have even degree.